# Port-forwarding via k8s cluster

Tags: networking, kubernetes

good day.
i have k8s cluster and gitlab installed on dedicated server (as typical application on real OS)
i have ingress on k8s which route traffic by host address to gitlab via externalName service

no i need to give access to ssh, so i create service without selector and coresponding  endpoint:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gitlab-service-ssh
  namespace: host
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 22
      nodePort: 30222
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: gitlab-service-ssh
  namespace: host
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 192.168.0.24
    ports:
    - port: 22
```

i can access to ssh from k8s cluster node via
`git clone ssh://git@git.xxxxxx:30222/XXXXX`
and it is work correctly

by if i try to access from any lan computer i receive
`ssh: connect to host git.xxxxx port 30222: Resource temporarily unavailable`

there is no any active firewall or other service on this port (i try to use different port  - same result)

so i dont understand there is my fault.

i use k8s of version 1.16 on bare metal with metallb as load balance, host machine under Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't have Nginx installed in the server and it blocks SSH by default. You have to `sudo ufw allow ssh`.

Also execute :  `netstat -an | select-string 30222`
to check status. Try to connect via IP not hostname.
Take a look: [ssh-host](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2478).

Comment: ufw status -> inactive, also i try to connect by ip and hostname - same result, netstat give me some clue - tcp6       0      0 :::30222                :::*                    LISTEN, so it listen only ipv6, but not ipv4.. try to investigate this direction and post update then get new info

Comment: still no luck there, i cannot find any way to specify protocol for selectorless service. for normal service there are both of protocol used (tcp, tcp6)

Comment: Did you take a look https://serverfault.com/questions/355086/managing-parallel-rules-for-ipv4-and-ipv6-iptables ?